# Catia vba, How to read and write properties of cartia object?

Tags: vba, catia

I want to use vba to read and write "*Description*" & "*Visualize in the Bill of Material*" of selected catia object. I use highlight in the picture below. Help me please, Thank you!

[image: Properties]

Comment: Please have a look at _DescriptionInst_ and _DescriptionRef_ property of the _Product_ object. AFAIK _Visualize in the Bill of Materia_ is not accessible via api.

Comment: @Shrotter, Thanks for your time! It's sad that it's not possible to read "visualize in the Bill of Material" parameter, this causes redundancy when i counting the quantity of part.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s as Selection
Set s = Catia.ActiveDocument.selection 'selection of your document

For i = 1 to s.Count2 'if your selection contains more than 1 selection
   Dim p as Product 
   Set p = s.Item2(i).LeafProduct 'leafproduct to get your product
   p.DescriptionInst = "test" 'to set your description
Next
```

It's not possible to get/set *Visualize in The Bill of Material*

Comment: So it can only be set manually.  I get it. Thanks you!